# Noisy limit of sinusoidal modulation of the frequency of a two level system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, noise, open-quantum-systems

I've been reading the paper [Motional Averaging in a Superconducting Qubit by Li et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.0675) from 2011, in which they study what happens when they modulate the frequency of a two level system. Specifically, they study a system with the Hamiltonian

\begin{equation}
H(t) = \frac{\hbar}{2}[\omega_0 + \xi(t)]\sigma_z
\end{equation} 
where $\xi(t)$ is a time dependent part of the two level system's energy splitting that they experimentally control. In the beginning of the paper they study this for $\xi(t)$ being random telegraph noise, which I am not so interested in.

However, they then move on to sinusoidal modulation of the frequency: they choose $\xi(t) = A \cos{\left(\Omega t \right)}$. They get interesting results from this, being that the problem results in the two level system not having a single resonance frequency but forming sidebands at $\omega = \omega_0 \pm k \Omega$ with $k = 0,1,2.$. where the amplitude of the sidebands are modulated with Bessel functions $J_k(A/\Omega)$. This is illustrated in figure 3 of the paper. The supplementary material has all the detials of the derivation. Now, this is rather interesting physics by itself, the formation of sidebands. However, what I am interested in is if we look at the above in a noisy limit.

The sinusoidal drive can be looked at in the frequency domain through its power spectral density, which is simply $
S(\omega) = A \delta(\omega\pm\Omega)$; a delta function at the frequency of the modulation. But in nature one rarely observes an actual delta function; there is usually some broadening. Take for example a quantum harmonic oscillator with finite lifetime, or say, a phononic mode. Their power spectral density is roughly that of a Lorentzian function:

\begin{equation}
S(\omega) = \frac{A}{1+\left(\frac{\omega\pm\Omega}{b}\right)^2}
\end{equation}

where I have introduced some width parameter $b$. So what I am now interested in, in this question, is what happens to the above physics of the sinusoidal drive and side band formation if we instead modulate the frequency of the two level system with such a noisy but still peaked power spectral density?

I imagine there will be different regimes that are relevant; we should more or less recover the sinusoidal drive for $b \rightarrow 0$, and thus also the sidebands. But what happens to them when the broadening becomes larger? I somehow imagine that the modulation amplitude will now include $b$ as well, at least in a hand wavy way. Of course the dynamics will also no longer be completely coherent; the noise will induce some dephasing, which may be relevant. Intuitively I feel like the sidebands should still form though, given some specific parameter hierarchy.

Comment: Exactly what do you want to know? You could reasonably easily compute the spectral density of the qubit oscillations.

Comment: @DanielSank What I am interested in is what changes compared to the coherent tone. Do we still get sidebands? How does the broadness of the noise influence this? Do they change the modulation amplitude for example? Do they result in a sideband that has finite width?

Comment: Have you tried working it out yourself? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I am not sure where to start. In their derivation they use a number of unitary transformations to get rid of the time dependent drive terms for the energy level modulation and the drive, which are in terms of sinusoidal functions. If I add a general time dependent modulation $\delta (t)$ I don't see how one would do this transformation as I do now know the unitary.

Comment: Maybe I should add that I'm not thinking of negligible broadening of the signal. For an $\omega$ of about 5 GHz I'd think about a FWHM ($=2b$) of about 10 MHz. That is not huge, but it is something.

Comment: There is a type in the comment before the last one; the last sentence should be  If I add a general time dependent modulation $\delta(t)$ I don't see how one would do this transformation as I don't now know the unitary based on that I only know the modulation spectral density.

Comment: I find the initial use of $\delta(t)$ confusing since it (i) is not a Dirac delta, (ii) conflicts with the symbol $\delta(\omega\pm\Omega)$ below, and (iii) doesn't match the paper. Please consider rephrasing it.

Comment: That said, I'm with Daniel on this one - I don't really understand what you want to know. Sidebands in what? I don't find the coherent-drive sideband results surprising at all; they're a vanilla example of a Floquet ladder and represent the Brillouin-zone-like spectrum of the Floquet hamiltonian. However, once you add noise, the Floquet formalism becomes inapplicable, and you can't speak of quasienergy eigenvalues ─ so I don't understand where you want to look for sidebands or whatnot.

Comment: Thanks for those comments @EmilioPisanty. You were definitely right about the confusing usage of delta. As for what I want to know, it essentially comes down to how such a noisy-drive compares to the coherent-drive sideband scenario, given that they are similar in terms of power spectral density, and the frequency components that enabled the coherent sideband dynamics are also available.  So I would personally expect that also in this scenario you observe these type of sidebands, in some form. I was looking for a way to (mathematically) describe this, like one can do for the coherent case.